# how to translate simple Excel VBA routine do VB.net

Tags: visual-studio

I need help to translate the following two subs (two different routines) that I employ on my custom built excel addin from VBA do VB.NET. They are part of an addin + ribbon that I'm building.

This one sets the excel calculation to manual or semiautomatic depending on the current estate.

```
Sub Calculation()
If Application.Calculation = xlManual Then
    Application.Calculation = xlSemiautomatic
    MsgBox ("Cálculo automático")
Else
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    MsgBox ("Cálculo manual")
End If
End Sub
```

And this on sets all worksheets zoom to 85%.

```
Sub set_zoom()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Let me give you some context.  I have this addin that I've build in the excel VBA editor. I'm trying to import it to vb.net so I can add an interface and some buttons - this way I can share it to my office colleagues.

My addin is pretty long and I will not bother you asking for help to translate it all, though I need the basics to start. So, I'm really struggling to translate the two subs above. Sure those are pretty simple routines but they considerably improve our productivity. I guess that as I learn how to translate simple ones as the two above, I can improve to translate some more nasty routines that I have in my addin. Right?

Thanks!